# Annotation causes OperationalError "field isn't in GROUP BY" in some cases

Tags: python, mysql, django, django-orm

I'm try to annotate a certain model as follows:

```
items = MyModel.objects.all()
aggregated_items = items.annotate(Max('othermodel__some_integer_field'))
```

When inspecting `aggregated_items` I get an `OperationalError`:

```
<repr(<parler.managers.TranslatableQuerySet at 0x7f69977066d0>) failed: django.db.utils.OperationalError: (1055, "'mydatabase.myapp_mymodel.some_unrelated_field' isn't in GROUP BY")>
```

Odd thing is, this works perfectly fine on one database server but not on another. I've obtained the underlying query through `connections.queries` and ran it on both databases and again, one database is happy to execute this query while the other one returns an error.

Why could this be happening? As far as I can tell the schemes are equal but I suspect that there's some difference in the settings of both database servers. Database server one runs on MySQL 5.5.44 while the other one runs on 5.5.41. Another important thing to note is that I'm using a custom manager from the internationalization library [`django-parler`](http://django-parler.readthedocs.org/).

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Your second database is working on [ONLY_FULL_GROUP_BY](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/sql-mode.html#sqlmode_only_full_group_by) mode.

Try to overwrite mode:

```
DATABASES = {
    'default': {
        'ENGINE': 'django.db.backends.mysql',
        'OPTIONS': {
            'sql_mode': 'traditional',
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Yes, that's the root cause of the issue. Thanks!

Comment: This fixed my OperationalError 1055 as well, so thanks!  From other places, I am reading that turning off ONLY_FULL_GROUP_BY might put me at risk of poorly formed queries though?  Or is django keeping me safe from poorly formed queries?